# How can I read a text file with StreamReader selectively?

Tags: c#

I am trying to use a loop to collect all the elements in a text file and select out of those elements specific ones to display.

```
            {
                string lines = File.ReadLines(path).Where(line => line.StartsWith("Name: ")).ToString();
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    MessageList.Items.Add(lines);
                }
            }
```

The idea with this code is for the file stream to parse the entire document and only select the lines that start with Name:, ignoring all other ones so I can add the

I can't seem to get around the syntax error within the condition of the foreach loop. It says I'm trying to convert between char and string and the compiler is confused by my request. I've tried doing this with and without invoking ToString(), I've also tried it by declaring lines as a var instead of a string. I tried to do this without the lambda expression

Comment: Remove `ToString()`. Why did you put it there?

Comment: Delete .ToString() from the first statement.

Comment: What is the declaration for MessageList ?

Comment: Also change MessageList.Items.Add(lines); to MessageList.Items.Add(line);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**lines** is not a string. It will be of type

```
IEnumerable<string>
```

if you let it.

If you use var instead the compiler will figure out the type for you.  If you hover your mouse over the **lines** or **line** variable in your IDE it will let you know the type.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(path).Where(line => line.StartsWith("Name: "));
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    MessageList.Items.Add(line);
}
```

If you want to be explicit about the type, this would be the code.

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(path).Where(line => 
line.StartsWith("Name: "));
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    MessageList.Items.Add(line);
}
```

About var - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var

About File.Readlines including the return type - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-6.0

You could also use:-

```
File.ReadLines(path).Where(line => line.StartsWith("Name: ")).ToList()
    .ForEach(line => { MessageList.Items.Add(line); });
```